# Convert raw string to JSON format

Tags: arrays, json

Hi I just have a question on how can I convert this API response into json data. I tried using explode but the response seems like separated into array.

```
StatCode: 11
StatName: cancelled
OrderID: OP_AFIFAH_6889
Amount: 1.10
TranID: 143519171
Domain: test
BillingDate: 2019-11-26 16:58:49
BillingName: test
VrfKey: test
Channel: credit
Currency: MYR
ErrorCode: CC_000
ErrorDesc: Successful Payment :
```

Maybe something like this

```
{

"StatCode": 11,
"StatName": "cancelled",
"OrderID": "OP_AFIFAH_6889",
"Amount": 1.10,
"TranID": 143519171
etc..
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you specify what tools you are using. Because the response will differ greatly depending on what you are using.

Comment: *"I tried using explode"*: which language? PHP?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is changing the API to return the JSON object. If you don't have access to the API, I wrote a simple javascript for you which can convert it to the JSON object:

```js
function toJSON(input) {
    const lines = input.split('\n')
    const result = []

    for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {        
        if (!lines[i])
            continue;
        const obj = {}
        const currentline = lines[i].split(':')

        obj[currentline[0]] = currentline[1]
        result.push(obj)
    }
    return JSON.stringify(result)
}

console.log(toJSON(`StatName: cancelled
OrderID: OP_AFIFAH_6889
Amount: 1.10
TranID: 143519171
Domain: test
BillingDate: 2019-11-26 16:58:49
BillingName: test
VrfKey: test
Channel: credit
Currency: MYR
ErrorCode: CC_000
ErrorDesc: Successful Payment :`)
);
```

Comment: Thanks this would be helpful since I don't have the access to the API.

Comment: Can we consolidate the output into 1 json file?

Comment: Yup. You can do it by NodeJS filesystem (fs)

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    {
        "StatName": "cancelled",
        "OrderID": "OP_AFIFAH_6889",
        "Amount": 1.10,
        "TranID": 143519171,
        "Domain": "test",
        "BillingDate": "2019-11-26 16:58:49",
        "BillingName": "test",
        "VrfKey": "test",
        "Channel": "credit",
        "Currency": "MYR",
        "ErrorCode": "CC_000",
        "ErrorDesc": "Successful Payment"
    }
]
```

Note: Amount and TranID values are both numbers ,if you want them to be a type of string kindly add double quotes to them.
Thanks